# Add indication that you have a badge on the description page

Tags: feature-request, badges

I was just reading the [2012 Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election) page, and saw the badge requirements.  I noticed that when you are on one of the badge pages, eg [Deputy](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1002/deputy), there is no indication that you have a particular badge, like you do on the [badge summary page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges).

Something like

[image]

would be nice.

Comment: +1. I would have up-voted more if you had hand-drawn a red circle around your added check-mark.

Comment: Really surprised this has never been suggested before!

Comment: Since some tags can be awarded multiple times, a counter next to the checkmark might be useful.

Comment: @vcsjones Yes, and [on the badge summary page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134606/164012).

Comment: @AndrewBarber, here you go...