# Add counter next to checkmark on badge summary page

Tags: feature-request, badges, design

Along with another user's recent suggestion that [appropriate checkmarks be added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134590/164012) to badge description pages, I propose that a counter be added to the checkmarks, as appropriate:

[image]

With MPD's proposed checkmark:

[image]